# Why do Javascript "class" implementations overwrite the class name with an identically-named function declaration?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, closures, iife

I'm studying Coffeescript's output to try and get a solid understanding of what's happening behind-the-scenes. When I declare a new class Person, a variable named Person is created containing an IIFE.

```
var Person;

Person = (function() {
  function Person() {
    this.doThing();
  }

  Person.prototype.doThing = function() {};

  return Person;

})();
```

What's throwing me here, is that the IIFE itself contains a named function declaration called Person. Does this overwrite the original Person variable, or does Javascript consider this a new scope? When doThing is added to Person's prototype, which object is that specifically referring to?

Perhaps my question betrays a deeper confusion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIFE, being a function, creates a new scope so that all of the `'class'` logic is nicely hidden away. The `Person` inside the IIFE is returned and assigned to the `Person` outside of it, but if the IIFE returned something else, then that is what the outer `Person` would be.

`doThing` is assigned to the prototype `Person` inside, but again since `Person` is returned, it is the same function object references inside the IIFE.